# How to decode ASN1 bytes to extract information?

Tags: java, decode, asn.1

I am trying to decode ASN1 using PER encoding , I have as input Hexa string for exemple :
       " 04 39 04 9E B7 DB 60 50 10 0D 0A 90 D8 24 B0 0A 76 AB 9A" 
   and I want to extract from this input information like that :

```
 UL-CCCH-Message

message: cellUpdate (0)

    cellUpdate

        u-RNTI

            srnc-Identity: 0e40 [bit length 12, 4 LSB pad bits, 0000 1110   0100 .... decimal value 228]

            s-RNTI: 127ad0 [bit length 20, 4 LSB pad bits, 0001 0010  0111 1010  1101 .... decimal value 75693]

        startList: 4 items

            Item 0

                STARTSingle

                    cn-DomainIdentity: ps-domain (1)

                    start-Value: b6c0a0 [bit length 20, 4 LSB pad bits, 1011 0110  1100 0000  1010 .... decimal value 748554]
```

any one have an idea how to do it with java ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing library rather than writing your own. Consider http://harmony.apache.org/subcomponents/classlibrary/asn1_framework.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the ASN.1 specification to feed to an ASN.1 compiler.  The ASN.1 compiler will generate an encoder/decoder to convert the binary data to a decoded Java object.  You can find a great list of ASN.1/Java compilers at http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx (some free, some commercial).

Comment: So to more undrestand what I will do : first I should include a ASN1 compiler to my java project this compiler will take in charge the decoding of incomming messages ?

Comment: The ASN.1 compiler will generate Java code  that you would include in your project to decode incoming messages.